# How to have a second color for a drawing group in wpf

Tags: wpf, drawing

I need to be able to draw horizontal lines against a background color, say red. I have the lines being drawn, but I don't know how to set the background color. Right now, the background is white.[image]

```
GeometryGroup stdGeometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
DrawingBrush db = new DrawingBrush();
GeometryDrawing stdDrawing = new GeometryDrawing(null, pen, stdGeometryGroup);
if (stdDrawing != null)
{
   db.Drawing = stdDrawing;
   db.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
   db.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
   db.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, 30, 30);
   db.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 4, 4);
   db.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
   db.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;

   db.Transform = new RotateTransform(45, 0.5, 0.5);
   stdGeometryGroup.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 15), new Point(30, 15)));
   menuItem.Background = db;
```

}

In this case, menuItem is a Telerik RadMenuItem. The Pen is black.

Comment: You can use a drawinggroup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-composite-drawin  Each drawing in that can have different colour.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the info.